# SUMIFs function within VBA not working correctly

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function GRIDSALES(rev_date As Date, grid_date As Date) As Variant

      Application.Volatile (True)

               Set Final_Price = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$H:$H")
               Set Team = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DO:$DO")
               Set First_PD = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$Q:$Q")

                GRIDSALES1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
                              Final_Price _
                              , Team, "<>9" _
                             , First_PD, ">=" & rev_date, First_PD, "<=EoMonth(" & grid_date & ")")

       End Function
```

VBA code above complies without any error but does not generate an answer.   I am trying to create a UDF that’s sums the Final Price for all sales teams (excluding team 9) between two dates `rev_date` and `grid_date`.  What am I missing?

Comment: I would break it up into pieces, and see what `GRIDSALES1` is for only those values such that `Team <> 9`, then add on the `First_PD` criteria and see if you get results, then combine all 3 together.  Also, check what `">=" & rev_date` comes up as in the debugger (during execution, highlight that grouping in the editor, right click and `Add Watch`) to make sure it makes sense.  DO the same for the `"<=EoMonth(" & grid_date & ")"` portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despise "hardcode" the objetive range of the sumif (antipattern?) the 1 in GRIDSALES1 and `"<=EoMonth("` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(grid_date, 0)` , that sunifs is has results as double it should be as:

```
Function ASALES(rev_date As Date, grid_date As Date) As Double

Dim Final_Price As Range
Dim Team As Range
Dim First_PD As Range
Application.Volatile (True)

Set Final_Price = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H5:$H11")
Set Team = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:E11")
Set First_PD = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5:F11")

ASALES = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
    Final_Price _
    , Team, "<>9" _
    , First_PD, ">=" & rev_date _
    , First_PD, "<=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(grid_date, 0))


End Function
```

Comment: This seems to have worked in terms of producing an actual result. Unfortunately the result being produced is complete in correct - it is over double what we know it should be. I wasn't quite sure was you meant by #it has results as double is should be' or at least what was causing it. 

Thanks in advance for your time. 

Obviously I can't show all the figures etc we are using but can you see anything else wrong? Anything that may

Comment: @James double is the type of data that handles, if I´m right is double precision.

Answer (score 1):

Your output should be the function name.  Change GRIDSALES1 to GRIDSALES.

Comment: Hi, we have tried this one but despite the change it is still not working. Trying out the above answer now. 

Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @James, yeah, I was afraid of that. I think the next step is to follow @Alen's suggestion that you have to use Application.Worksheetfunction.EOMONTH to call EOMONTH in your code.

Comment: That's helped us make some progress, thanks. See above for the new problem!